# Why do countries go to the UN rather than lobbying to the super/great powers?

Tags: united-nations

Super/great powers have the ability to bend/flout international laws.

For instance, (1) in Libya, GNA is the UN-recognized govt. But France is backing Haftar, (2) Israel is [annexing the West Bank](https://indianexpress.com/article/explained/what-is-israels-west-bank-annexation-plan-6486659/) with the backing of the USA, (3) [Russia bombed civilians in Syria](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/02/world/middleeast/united-nations-syria-idlib-russia.html), (4) [India in Kashmir](https://thewire.in/security/kashmiri-child-at-centre-of-propaganda-war-says-police-killed-grandfather), (5) China in [Xinjiang](https://foreignpolicy.com/2020/07/01/china-documents-uighur-genocidal-sterilization-xinjiang/) + [Tibet](https://bylinetimes.com/2020/06/22/will-the-eu-start-standing-up-to-china-over-repression-in-tibet/).

But, still countries try to go to the UN and try to make their cases by lecturing in the UNGA and contacting UNSG. E.g. Pakistan is contacting UNSG. India is taking HK issue in the UN, and so on.

Why?

Why don't they just simply lobby the super/great powers?

Comment: The great powers mostly are in it for themselves and, even when relatively well-intentioned, can step over a lot of toes.  France or the  UK for example often sees things through a lens of what weapons they can get you to buy.  Russia is only a good fit for a country with a particular (unsavory) profile.  The US has a fair bit of baggage when it comes to 3rd world countries and China is only just getting into that business and is  not/may not turn out to be all that benign either.  The UN is a better bet in many cases, esp if there isn't a preceding alignment with one of the powers.

Comment: -1. How come Israel in this list? annexing Gaza? please provide references for this specific claim. Or Russia bombing civilians? references? or India or China.

Comment: @dEmigOd The planned annexation of Gaza by Isreal has been part of the news cycle for days now, e.g. https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-53139808.

Comment: this is a paywall link, if it indeed says a word about Gaza - you should demand a refund

Comment: @dEmigOd Neither the link in the question, nor Polygnome's BBC link, are paywalled. I can see them both just fine. (They also both describe the impending annexation of the *West Bank*, not Gaza - OP has already corrected his mistake, Polygnome evidently made the same mistake.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all cases you mention, the losing side had failed already at convincing the powers that matter. So lobbying the UN Security Council is pointless: the Great Power involved will veto any resolution.

All those on the losing side are left with, is to lobby at the club for countries that do not matter. In other words: the UN General Assembly. They might even succeed at convincing enough countries to pass a resolution, but UN General Assembly resolutions don't matter in practice. Only the Security Council resolutions matter.

> Why do countries go to the UN rather than lobbying to the super/great powers?

**When all better options have failed, why not try the UN?**

Answer (score 7):

Going to the UN does, functionally, involve lobbying the great powers.  You could speak with the French, American, and Chinese ambassadors to your country or you could go to the UN and speak to the French, American, and Chinese ambassadors to the UN.  You're ultimately talking to the same major power brokers.  In one case, you just have the benefit that all of them happen to be in the same building together.

Going to the UN lets you leverage the clout of other countries.  If you convince a bunch of smaller EU countries to support your position, that puts pressure on the European members of the Security Council to go along with you.  You can make it politically costly for one of the great powers to go against the grain.  The permanent members of the Security Council don't generally take lightly to vetoing Security Council resolutions-- if you can convince a majority of the members, you can change the calculus so it isn't worth it to the great power to oppose you.

Going to the UN also ideally forces countries to take sides.  If you lobby a great power directly, you're likely to get a lot of political double-speak.  The country you're lobbying probably doesn't want to invest the political capital to take sides publicly so they're likely to nod their heads and agree that it's a tough situation and do nothing.  If you go to the UN, you can hopefully force a vote which can change the political calculus.  No nation particularly wants to spend its political capital, for example, to denounce the occupation of Tibet because it is generally far more interested in keeping good relations with China.  But few democratic nation want to publicly vote against a resolution on Tibetan autonomy because that looks really craven to their domestic population.

Comment: @user366312 The UN is not a fairy grandmother that grants your wishes. If almost every country sides with India, then when Pakistan goes to the UN *which is formed by those very same countries that side*, the answer is not very different (although usually in a more neutral tone). Maybe you feel that India is on the wrong on the Kashmir issue, but most of the world does not agree with you.